# Limited printed rows when running select query using postgres bash on linux

Tags: bash, postgresql, centos

I have a CentOS linux machine that has postgres DB installed on.
I connected to this machine via ssh and I ran the next command in order to print a certain table.

```
sudo -u postgres bash -c "psql -d db -c \"SELECT *
    FROM accounts;\"" 2>/dev/null
```

this table contains 800 rows BUT the output of this command only prints 38 rows.
Can anyone tell me how I can fix it?

Comment: The most likely explanation is that you connected to a server/database other than the one you think you did, and that that one has 38 rows.  But when something weird is happening, throwing away stderr is a poor strategy for figuring out what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to change the end of the command from 2>/dev/null to >/dev/null